# XPath descendant axis

Tags: xml, xpath

I am confused as to why XStylus returns this results when running a query regarding the descendant axis.

I have the following XML file:

```
<?xml version=”1.0”?>
<!DOCTYPE BookStore System “BookStore.dtd”>
<BookStore BookStoreID=”BS112” Name =”CheapBooks” Location=”London” OwnerName =”Mr. Black”>
    <Books BookID =”BK111” Title=”Introduction to reading” Authors =”Ian Green”>
    </Books>
    <Books BookID =”BK112” Title=”Introduction to Sleeping” Authors =”Peter White”>
    </Books>
    <Staff StaffID =”S333” Name =”Ana Car”>
        <Manager ManagerID=”MG444” Name = “Mrs White” Address = “150 Wide Road, London SW10”>
        </Manager>
    </Staff>
</BookStore>
```

The document is well-formed and validates fine according to the tool. Now, I want to find the member of staff managed by the manager with ManagerID equal to MG444.

I use the following query:

```
 /child::BookStore/descendant:Staff[@ManageID='MG444']
```

my rationale been that I am looking for the child element of BookStore that has a Staff descendant which has a ManagerID attribute with the specific value. Stylus Studio returns nothing. If I run

```
 /child::BookStore/descendant:Staff
```

I get the whole Staff element, not just Manager. Why is that - is descendant not supposed to only look at descendants, not the current node and ignore attributes? Likewise, why does the first query does not work?

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for Staff element with a given ManagerId use this:

```
/child::BookStore/descendant::Staff[Manager/@ManagerID='MG444']
```

Because ManagerID is an attribute from Manager not from Stuff.
Or shorter

```
/BookStore//Staff[Manager/@ManagerID='MG444']
```

But Staff is child of BookStore also:

```
/BookStore/Staff[Manager/@ManagerID='MG444']
```

According your example `/child::BookStore/descendant:Staff`

This is looking for descendant Staff in BookStore. Which means searching for Staff as children of BookStore **in any deep**. it will only return Stuff entries.

Q: *I get the whole Staff element, not just Manager. Why is that - is descendant not supposed to only look at descendants, not the current node and ignore attributes?*

**This is right**: But your current node is BookStore.

If your are looking for Manage use:

```
/BookStore/descendant::Manager
```

or

```
BookStore/Staff/Manager
```

Update: 
Q: *is /child::BookStore/descendant:Staff not interpreted as look for all child elements in BookStore that have Staff as a descendant (or is my understanding of XPath completely wrong)? I am not looking for the manager, I am looking for the member of staff managed by that Manager.*

Looks like your mistake in the interpretation of current node for each step.

`child::BookStore` looks for any children which node-name is BookStore to the current node.
Because of `/`as "prefix" this an **absolute location path**.
For more information have a look to: [Location Path Expression](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_axes.asp)

And than `/descendant:Staffas` as **next step**: You are looking  for descendant with node-name Staff for the current node. But now the current nodes are the BookStore`s .

**Staff managed by that Manager**

```
/BookStore/Staff[Manager/@ManagerID='MG444']
```

Comment: is    /child::BookStore/descendant:Staff not interpreted as look for all child elements in BookStore that have Staff as a descendant (or is my understanding of XPath completely wrong)? I am not looking for the manager, I am looking for the member of staff managed by that Manager.

Comment: @hr_117's solution returns what you said you want. A shorter XPath expression to retrieve it would be: `//Staff[Manager[@ManagerID="MG444"]]`.

Comment: @Rolando Isidoro: Thanks. Yes sure this would probably the best one. But I dried to explain what is going on withe examples in question.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify

```
//BookStore/Staff/descendant::Manager[@ManageID='MG444']
```

in case you have more elements of `<Manager>`. After executing above query I am getting below result.

```
Array
(
    [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [@attributes] => Array
                (
                    [ManagerID] => MG444
                    [Name] => Mrs White
                    [Address] => 150 Wide Road, London SW10
                )

            [0] => 

        )

)
```

Comment: this would be you only the staff entity though; I want the member of staff who is managed by this manager, not the value of the manager himself. Also, why with descendant am I getting the current node as well?

Comment: Can you specify `<Member>` element? Because it is not mentioned in the specified XML structure?